# How do I resolve the unrecognized plugins by BOSS?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have 38 mods that are unrecognized by BOSS. I am informed by BOSS with the following:

> The following plugins were not found in the masterlist, and must be
> positioned manually, using your favourite mod manager or by using
> BOSS's user rules functionality. You can submit unrecognized plugins
> for addition to the masterlist directly from this log by clicking on a
> plugin and supplying a link and/or description of its contents in the
> panel that is displayed.

I have no idea what they're talking about in terms of "positioning manually" and "submitting the URL of the mod." Can someone help explain this?

Comment: One of the benefits of these plugin managers is that they control the order that the mods load, which helps alleviate issues with compatibility. In order for that to work, the tools need to know what those mods are, and thus be able to sort them appropriately. You happen to have mods that the tool is unaware of, and it's inviting you to effectively "register" them so that the tool can be improved with knowledge and configurations for those mods.

Comment: Also that log link is something on your local computer; we can't see it.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: "I have 38 mods that are unrecognized by NMM." You mean BOSS instead of NMM, right?

Comment: @Joachim unfortunately i have no experience with nmm/boss, only LOOT. I was speaking generally.

Comment: @galacticninja -  Yes.
How do I "manually reposition" these mods and what do they mean by submitting the URL of the mods?

Comment: @Roddy of the Frozen Peas  - Okay why are they telling me to submit download location and in the box it wants me to put a URL?
I was trying to resolve crashes when I travel to certain locations in the game and this was the information I was lead to; that BOSS was suppose to remedy those problems.

Comment: @ZadekielSephirah See my [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/385229/4797) below. Use [LOOT](https://loot.github.io/) instead of BOSS. LOOT does the same thing as BOSS. It does not require you to submit mod URLs nor manually reposition mods.

Answer (score 5):

Use [**LOOT**](https://loot.github.io/) instead of BOSS. BOSS and its masterlist of mods (which specifies how mods are to be optimally sorted) are no longer being maintained for Skyrim. LOOT does the same thing as BOSS, which is to optimally sort the load order of mods/plugins, and it is still being maintained for Skyrim.

According to [BOSS' webpage](https://boss-developers.github.io/) (emphasis mine):

> Using mods for **Skyrim**, Fallout 3 or Fallout: New Vegas? Use [LOOT](https://loot.github.io/) instead, as BOSS's support for those games is relatively poor and no longer maintained.

The BOSS message about "positioning manually" is because the mods' load order have to be sorted manually by the user as they are not in the (unmaintained) BOSS masterlist. "Submitting the URL of the mod" is supposed to be for the maintainers of the masterlist, so they can check the mod itself and verify its optimal load order and update the masterlist to include the mod's data. Since the BOSS masterlist is no longer being maintained, submitting the URL is pointless. You don't need to do either of these if you switch to using LOOT instead.

See [LOOT's FAQ page](https://loot.github.io/docs/help/LOOT-FAQs.html#boss-v3) for more info:

> #### Moving From BOSS
>
> ...
> **Do I have to switch from BOSS to LOOT?**
> No. However, BOSS is no longer maintained for games other than Oblivion, and LOOT generally provides superior functionality.
>
> **Is there anything I should bear in mind when switching to LOOT?**
> It's worth double-checking the load order LOOT gives you, in case it's gotten something wrong. Also, if you're not starting a new game, changing your load order may cause in-game issues. To avoid disaster, you can backup your load order as follows:
>
> 1. Make a backup of your current `.ess` save file, and its accompanying `.skse` file (if you have SKSE installed). These are found in the `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\Saves` folder.
> 2. Make a backup of your load order files, `plugins.txt` and `loadorder.txt` , which are found in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Skyrim` folder.
>
> That way, if something does go wrong, you have backups to roll back to. If you don't overwrite or delete save files, you don't need to back them up, so long as you can remember which save was made before you made the changes that caused problems.
> ...
> **How can LOOT not have unrecognised plugins?**
> To sort a plugin, BOSS needs it to be added to its masterlist, which is hand-ordered by its maintainers. LOOT instead reads the contents of each plugin to see which plugins conflict, etc. and uses that information to decide on the best ordering. This means that it can sort all plugins without needing them to become recognised first.
>
> **Does LOOT sort based only on plugin content?**
> No. While it can sort most plugins correctly, sometimes it gets things wrong, and LOOT's masterlist is used to provide metadata so that it can sort such plugins correctly. Unlike in BOSS, LOOT's masterlist doesn't give specific load order positions, which makes it more adaptable and easier to maintain.
>
> **How can the load order LOOT gives be right if BOSS gives a very different load order?**
> There can be more than one correct load order for a given set of plugins. For example, some plugins may not conflict or depend on each other, so their relative orders wouldn't matter. The load order BOSS gives is hand-made to look 'neat' as well as work, so plugins from the same mod will usually get grouped together, but LOOT doesn't know which plugins belong to which mod, so it just puts them where it thinks they work.

Comment: Okay!
So how do I get unrecognized plugins of mods recognized?
How does LOOT fix that and How do I do it?
This is all complicated and it now appears to me that all of this is meant for people with IT skills.
I have no idea as to how to fix all of this crashing in my game and when I youtube the information, they either fail to properly guide and explain or they will guide you to a certain extent and then demonstrate something that your computer doesn't do or have.
This is frustrating

Comment: Install LOOT and then run it, you don't need BOSS at all. As mentioned in the LOOT FAQ linked above, LOOT does not require that the plugins be recognized in a masterlist. The issue you encountered in BOSS will not be encountered in LOOT. You don't need to "get unrecognized plugins of mods recognized" with LOOT. If you need a guide, there is a readme/manual in the [LOOT page](https://loot.github.io/).

Comment: Okay.
I do have LOOT in my NMM.
I am just so frustrated with all of this crashing when I only have 116 mods and just bought a LEGION computer.
My gameplay smooth and the graphics are awesome.
I just hate all of this crashing when I walk through a door like  Dark Brotherhood, into certain areas or fast travel to certain locations

Comment: I mean, the problem isn't your computer in that case, it's that these mods are made my non-professional programmers (usually) with minimal quality control and testing -- and any testing they _do_ is likely in a vaccuum. As a mod author you can figure out compatibility with one or two other mods pretty easy. But 117 arbitrary ones? Not a chance. Package managers will help, but there's no guarantee that your mods are all compatible. @ZadekielSephirah

Comment: Okay, how do I get "Package managers?"
I also learned that 38 mods were unrecognized.
Those were the very mods that brought excitement and uniqueness to my game.

Comment: @ZadekielSephirah Are you still getting "unrecognized mod" error messages with LOOT? Not sure what exactly RoddyoftheFrozenPeas meant with package managers, but they might be referring to mod managers, e.g., software like NMM.

Comment: Yeah.
I have 38 unrecognized mods.
One of which is Better Vampires 8.5.
With the kind of mods I have of the 38, by removing them ( If I have to ) I will be reduced to a humdrum game with humdrum armors.
If only you could see what I mean you'de be envious

Comment: @ZadekielSephirah It is weird that LOOT (and *not* BOSS) still needs mod recognition. If you need more help, go to one of the forums dedicated to discussion of LOOT: at https://loot.github.io/ (See 'Forum Thread' or 'Discord Server' link in the left sidebar.)